# Vue 3 merging proxy objects refs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3

I tried merging the child refs with my parent refs. This worked previously in Vue 2, but now that I'm migrating to Vue 3, I'm encountering an error with the $set refs. However, $refs is dynamic and should be added to the main parent ref.

ParentComponent.vue

```
<template>
  <form
    method="post"
    :action="action"
    :novalidate="novalidate"
    :autocomplete="autocomplete"
    @submit="onFormSubmit"
  >
    <component
      :is="component.component"
      v-for="component in components"
      :key="component.props.key"
      :ref="component.props.ref"
      :field="component.props"
      @change="getState"
      :metadata="form.metadata"
    />
  </form>
</template>

<script>
import {
  serializeForm,
  instanceOfValueFormField,
  getFieldValueFromModel,
  submitForm,
  FormTracker,
  FormFetcher,
  TrackerFetcher,
} from '@sitecore-jss/sitecore-jss-forms';
import FieldFactory from './FieldFactory';
import Conditions from './Conditions';
import { markRaw } from 'vue';

export default {
  name: 'VueForm',
  props: {
    form: {
      type: Object,
      default: () => ({}),
    },
    sitecoreApiKey: {
      type: String,
      default: null,
    },
    sitecoreApiHost: {
      type: String,
      default: null,
    },
    params: {
      type: Object,
      default: null,
    },
    translations: {
      type: Object,
      default: () => ({}),
    },
    apiEndpoint: {
      type: String,
      default: null,
    },
    novalidate: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: true,
    },
    autocomplete: {
      type: String,
      default: 'on',
    },
    customFieldFactory: {
      type: Function,
      default: null,
    },
    customTrackerFetcher: {
      type: Object,
      default: null,
    },
    trackerEndpoint: {
      type: String,
      default: null,
    },
    onSubmit: {
      type: Function,
      default: null,
    },
    onAfterSubmit: {
      type: Function,
      default: null,
    },
  },
  data() {
    return {
      action: '',
      components: {},
      formState: {},
      conditions: {},
      submitButtonName: null,
      navigationStep: null,
      nextForm: null,
      errors: null,
      FormTracker: null,
      trackerFetcher: this.customTrackerFetcher || TrackerFetcher,
      fieldFactory: this.customFieldFactory || FieldFactory,
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    // render the form
    this.renderForm(this.form);
  },
  methods: {
    async onFormSubmit(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      const { currentTarget } = e;

      const submitButton = currentTarget.querySelector('button[type=submit]');
      submitButton.disabled = true;
      submitButton.setAttribute('data-loading', 'true');
      this.$emit('form-submit');

      if (this.navigationStep >= 0) {
        Object.keys(this.$refs).forEach((fieldKey) => {
        // I'm trying to validate this where all of the fields will be triggered
          if (this.$refs?.[fieldKey]?.[0]) {
            const isValid = this.$refs[fieldKey][0].validate();
            if (this.formState?.[fieldKey]?.isValid) {
              this.formState[fieldKey].isValid = isValid;
            }
          }
        });
      }
};
</script>
```

ChildComponent.vue

```
<template>
  <fieldset :class="field.model.cssClass" v-show="isVisible">
    <component
      :is="component.component"
      v-for="component in field.fields"
      :key="component.props.key"
      :ref="component.props.ref"
      :field="component.props"
    />
  </fieldset>
</template>

<script>
import BaseField from './BaseField.vue';
export default {
  name: 'FormSection',
  extends: BaseField,
  mounted() {
    console.log('Parent Refs', JSON.stringify(this.$parent.$refs));
    console.log('Refs', JSON.stringify(this.$refs));

     // Error in Vue 3 $set falsish
     this.$parent.$refs = { ...this.$parent.$refs, ...this.$refs };

  },
};
</script>
```

I've also tried methods like Object.assign and using a getter and setter, but they don't seem to add to the main parent refs.

[image]

Comment: Why `this.$parent`?

Comment: That is because it's refering to the parent component. I have edited the code @KaiKai

Comment: modify the parent node is not a good idea i think, do you means [`defineExpose`](https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#defineexpose)?